# Google cloud Compute Engine refuse outer access through apache2

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Today, I tried to make a blog with Google Cloud Platform.

So, I made a Computer Engine Instance and install Apache2 on Ubuntu 16.

And then, clicked the Outer IP address, but it show me "connection denied.."

Why this happen?

I allowed HTTPS % HTTP Traffic also.

And I can't find a menu like AWS's Security Group...

So, this problem irritate me...

(I'm not a English native, so documentation is so hard read.. please, give me a tip for this matter)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR** - You need to open up ports using firewall rules to allow ingress traffic into your VMs.

[Google Compute Engine (GCE) blocks all traffic to your VMs by default](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls#firewalls) for the purpose of keeping your infrastructure secure. You can open up ports as needed and manage the security yourself. The default created network has few exceptions in terms of allowing traffic from other VMs in the network, but still does not allow traffic from outside the network.

> ## [Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls#firewalls)
>
> Each VPC network has its own firewall controlling access to the
>   instances.
>
> All traffic to instances, even from other instances, is blocked by the
>   firewall unless firewall rules are created to allow it. The exception
>   is the default VPC network that is created automatically with each
>   project. This network has certain automatically created [default
>   firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/firewalls#default_firewall_rules).
>
> For all VPC networks except the automatically created `default` VPC
>   network, you must create any firewall rules you need. To allow
>   incoming network connections on a manually created VPC network, you
>   need to set up firewall rules to permit these connections. Each
>   firewall rule represents a single rule that determines what
>   connections are permitted to enter or leave instances. It is possible
>   to have many rules and to be as general or specific with these rules
>   as you need. For example, you can create a firewall rule that allows
>   all traffic through port 80 to all instances, or you can create a rule
>   that only allows traffic from one specific IP or IP range to one
>   specific instance.
>
> Firewall rules are connection tracking, and therefore only regulate
>   the initial connection. Once a connection has been established with an
>   instance, traffic is permitted in both directions over that
>   connection.

Since you say `apache2` package on Ubuntu, the instructions I share here will guide you on how to open up port `80` on your VM and make it accessible through the VM's public IP. You can do the same for any additional ports as needed.

## [Using gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/) to allow ingress traffic for `tcp:80` into your VM

```
# Create a new firewall rule that allows INGRESS tcp:80 with VMs containing tag 'allow-tcp-80'
gcloud compute firewall-rules create rule-allow-tcp-80 --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags allow-tcp-80 --allow tcp:80

# Add the 'allow-tcp-80' tag to a VM named VM_NAME
gcloud compute instances add-tags VM_NAME --tags allow-tcp-80

# If you want to list all the GCE firewall rules
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
```

## [Using Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/using-firewalls) to allow ingress traffic for `tcp:80` into your VM

1. `Menu -> Networking -> Firewall Rules`
2. `Create Firewall Rule`
3. Choose the following settings for the firewall rule:

   1. `Name` for the rule - `rule-allow-tcp-80` or any other name you prefer for this firewall rule.
   2. `Direction` is `ingress`
   3. `Action on match` is `Allow`
   4. `Targets` is `Specified target tags`
   5. `Target tags` is `allow-tcp-80`
   6. `Source IP ranges` is `0.0.0.0/0` (or if you have a set of IP ranges you know will be the only ones accessing this, use them instead for stronger restriction)
   7. `Protocols and ports` is `tcp:80`
   8. Select `Create` button to create this firewall rule.
4. Once you've created the above firewall rule you will need to add the tag `allow-tcp-80` to all the instances where this rule needs to be applied. In your case:

   1. Open up the GCE `VM Instances` page
   2. Select the instance where Jenkins is running
   3. In the `VM instance details` page, select the `Edit` link on the very top.
   4. In the `Network Tags` box, enter `allow-tcp-80` to apply the tag to this instance.
   5. Select `Save` to save the changes.

Now give it a few seconds to a few minutes for the changes to take effect and you will be able to access the jenkins web URL.

You can also go through the documentation for [**Firewall rules**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/firewalls) to get a better understanding of how they work and how to configure them.

**WARNING:** By using a source range of `0.0.0.0/0`, you're opening up the port on the VM to the entire internet. This lets clients anywhere in the world to connect to the application running on this port. Be fully aware of the security implications of doing this.