# Expose ports on google cloud vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have two projects on google cloud. First one has been set up 15 hours ago and working fine, port 8080 is expose properly and i can access it.

Right now i'm trying to do absolutely the same with another project. I've created the same instance of vm in there with the same configs, entered the same commands using ssh connection. But i can't connect app to this server.

I've tried to create another instance of the vm on first project and it works, but whatever i create on the second project - i can't get access to it.

I assume, something wrong with the project configs, and therefore no details about VM's contents are provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Double check and compare your firewall rules in both the projects. You're most likely missing firewall rules to allow incoming traffic to port `8080` on your instances in the project where it is not working, whereas the other project has these rules configured.

### [Default Firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/firewalls#default_firewall_rules)

Google Compute Engine firewall by default blocks all ingress traffic (i.e. incoming network traffic) to your Virtual Machines. If your VM is created on the default network (which is usually the case), few ports like 22 (`ssh`), 3389 (`RDP`) are allowed.

The [default firewall rules are described here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/firewalls#default_firewall_rules).

### Opening ports for ingress

The [ingress firewall rules are described in detail here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/firewalls#ingress_cases).

The recommended approach is to create a firewall rule which allows incoming traffic to your VMs (containing a specific tag you choose) on port `8080` . You can then associate this tag only to the VMs where you will want to allow ingress `8080`.

The steps to do this using `gcloud`:

```
# Create a new firewall rule that allows INGRESS tcp:8080 with VMs containing tag 'allow-tcp-8080'
gcloud compute firewall-rules create rule-allow-tcp-8080 --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags allow-tcp-8080 --allow tcp:8080

# Add the 'allow-tcp-8080' tag to a VM named VM_NAME
gcloud compute instances add-tags VM_NAME --tags allow-tcp-8080

# If you want to list all the GCE firewall rules
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
```

Here is [another stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44645115/380757) which walks you through how to allow ingress traffic on specific ports to your VM using Cloud Console Web UI (in addition to `gcloud`).

### Operating System level firewall rules

Since you have not mentioned if you're using any of the [public Google Compute Engine images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images) or [Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/) images or a custom image of your choice, I also wanted to mention that even if you configure GCE firewall rules to allow incoming traffic to reach your VM, your OS level firewall could still very well reject the traffic.

[Google's Container-Optimized OS images have this feature turned on](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/firewall) where it blocks all ingress ports except for port `22` (SSH).

Comment: I did this for my GPU attached VM and it didn't work, nothing showed up. I have the same container on CloudRun working without issue. I'm really curious what other checks I can do to figure out why

Comment: Turns out, I checked the GCP VM logs and the service account didn't have access to the cloud storage objects to get the container so it never started. Updated the IAM to have storage viewer and it worked